# Calculating gradient for inner product of variable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, inner-products, matrix-calculus

The problem is formulated as follows:

Let $U\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times R}$ denote the variable matrix. $A_i\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ and $y_i$ is a scalar
$$
f(U) = \frac{1}{2m}\sum^m_{i=1}(\langle{A_i, UU^T}\rangle-y_i)^2
$$

Compute the gradient of $f(U)$ over $U$.

I have never dealt with inner products much before and am confused how to take the gradient for this function. I know that

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \langle f, g \rangle = \langle f(t), g^{\prime}(t) \rangle + \langle f^{\prime}(t), g(t) \rangle
$$

But if you do this then the matrix dimensions do not work. Also not sure if this is even correct as you are dealing with a variable matrix. Any help would be great as I am pretty lost on how to begin.

Comment: I'm confused by the quantity $\Big(\langle A_i,UU^T\rangle-y_i\Big)$ -- the first term is a scalar but $y_i$ is a matrix. Either there's a missing identity matrix multiplying the first term, or $y_i$ is actually a scalar.  Is $f(U)$ itself a scalar or a matrix?

Comment: Your right, it is a scalar, editing it. I was trying to write it concisely and got mixed up. $f(U)$ is a scalar

Comment: Which is the inner product? I guess it is $<A,B>=\sum_{ij} A_i B_i$ ?

Comment: @Miguel You are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ease of typing, I'll use a colon to denote the inner product, i.e.
$$A:B = \langle A,B\rangle$$
Define a vector $v$, whose $i^{th}$ component is given by
$$v_i = A_i:(UU^T) - y_i$$
and a matrix $M$ equal to the mean of the $A_i$ matrices
(weighted by the components of $v$)
$$M = \frac 1m\sum_{i=1}^m v_iA_i$$
Then the function can be written as
$$f = \frac 1{2m}\;\sum_{i=1}^m v_i\,v_i$$
Calculate the gradient of this function as follows
$$\eqalign{
df &= \frac 1m\;\sum_{i=1}^m v_i\,dv_i \\
   &= \frac 1m\;\sum_{i=1}^m v_i\,A_i:d(UU^T) \\
   &= M:d(UU^T) \\
   &= M:(dU\,U^T+U\,dU^T) \\
   &= (M+M^T):(dU\,U^T) \\
   &= \left(M+M^T\right)U:dU \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial U}
   &= \left(M+M^T\right)U \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This makes sense but I am unclear how you go from step 4 to step 5 in the gradient calculation. Could you elaborate what you are doing to get this?

Comment: An alternative expression for the inner product is 
$A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)\;$ and the step that you're asking
about follows from well-known properties of the trace.

Comment: Thanks. I will do more research