# Inner product derivative problem

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, matrix-calculus

This question follows from [Calculating gradient for inner product of variable matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3869831/621802) which was very helpful. I am now trying to calculate the Hessian with respect to variable matrix U and have a quick follow up question. These are some of the basic forms defined in the previous question:

Using notation $$\langle A, B \rangle = A:B$$
Let $U\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times R}$ denote the variable matrix. $A_i\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ and $y_i$ is a scalar

$$v_i = A_i:(UU^T) - y_i$$

$$M = \frac 1m\sum_{i=1}^m v_iA_i$$

To solve for the Hessian(U), I need to find $dM$:

$$\eqalign{
dM &= \frac 1m\sum_{i=1}^m dv_iA_i \\
&= \frac 1m\sum_{i=1}^m dv_iA_i \\
&= \frac 1m\sum_{i=1}^m (A_i:d(UU^T))A_i \\
&= \frac 1m\sum_{i=1}^m (A_i:(dUU^T + UdU^T))A_i \\
}$$

Then I use the method of the 4th step in the gradient derivation in the linked question to get the next line:

$$\eqalign{
&= \frac 1m\sum_{i=1}^m A_i\,((A_i+A_i^T)U:dU) \\
}$$

My question is can I use the same method that was used in the previous question of sort of dividing the right side by $dU$ to get $\frac {dM} {dU}$? I am not sure because of the extra $A_i$ term.

Comment: Your expression for $dM$ is correct and it can be rearranged as suggested, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial M}{\partial U} &= \frac 1m\sum_{i=1}^m A_i\star(A_iU+A_i^TU) \\
}$$
Note that this result is a fourth-order tensor (the "extra" $A_i$ term was a hint).

The $\star$ symbol is the tensor product defined such that 
$$\eqalign{
\Gamma &= A\star B\\ \Gamma_{ijk\ell} &= A_{ij}B_{k\ell}
}$$

Comment: Thank you for answering, this matrix calculus is new to me